# Generating multiple random integer number with fixed sum = 100 in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Based on the codes, i want to randomize the integer where there are specific range specify but in last three array need to have 100 in total. the sum of the last three array cannot be exceed than 100. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
self.position = np.array([rd.randint(0,2), rd.randint(0,2), rd.randint(0,100), rd.randint(0,50), rd.randint(0,1)])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can generate n random numbers with given sum using the following function

```
import random

def numbers_with_sum(n, k):
    """n numbers with sum k"""
    if n == 1:
        return [k]
    num = random.randint(1, k)
    return [num] + numbers_with_sum(n - 1, k - num)
```

This will produce the following output

```
In [1]: numbers_with_sum(3, 100)                                               
Out[1]: [75, 9, 16]
```

Now to generate a random array with sum of last 3 numbers as 100 just create a normal random array with (n - 3) elements and append it to the array you get from `number_with_sum(3, 100)`.